# Be in awe of my brilliance!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix might debase and diminish.
>   My infix might lie before stone and tree.
>   My suffix, Edna Mode might say no to.
>   Put me together and be in awe of my brilliance!

**What is the word?**

Comment: *It finally happened. I finally did one of these.  Thanks [Riley](/q/62349) for leading the way!*

Comment: Rubio, the blasphemy! How can you? Jk, looks pretty good

Comment: Also I bow humbly beneath the awe of the holy dog....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My prefix might debase and diminish.

> The prefix **SUB** can indicate that something is lower than something else.

My infix might lie before stone and tree.

> Two different kinds of **LIME** can go before each.

My suffix, Edna Mode might say no to.

> When the fashion designer said "No capes!", everybody thought she was talking about the the superheroes' wide cloaks, but she was, of course, talking about a headland, a **NESS**.

Put me together and be in awe of my brilliance!

> Words of true **SUBLIMENESS**.

Answer (score 1):

(Partial)

Well I would be really disappointed if your suffix wasn't

> a cape

which leaves us with not that many words, so even though it's probably wrong, I'm gonna go with

> **inscape**,  which is a philosophical concept related to the divinity of one's individualness (hence the title),

with the prefix

> "in" being the privative (and thus, diminishing) "in" as in "insufficient",

and as for the infix..

> I dunno, if you go through the National Strength and Conditionning Association, maybe you'll become resilient as a tree and hard as a rock ?

Comment: Good try, but that's clearly a no-go on that putative infix. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if these kind of puzzles enable us to give or take some latters, so I'm just gonna take a wild guess...

*My prefix might debase and diminish.*

> **ruin**

*My infix might lie before stone and tree.*

> **unesco** as an Unesco World Heritage sign is tipically present in national parks (stones and trees)

*My suffix, Edna Mode might say no to.*

> **cape** from the movie The Incredible

*Put me together and be in awe of my brilliance!*

> ruin + unesco + cape = **RuneScape**, the famous MMORPG

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen letters of the parts dropped or added from the final word without being specifically called out in the puzzle (and, at that, only once to insert an awkward single letter).  The final word should be a clearer match than this, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer:
My prefix might debase and diminish.

> Not sure - could be a math/music reference?

My infix might lie before stone and tree.

> This could be scissors (or a form), with stone = rock, and tree = paper (rock, paper, scissors!)

My suffix, Edna Mode might say no to.

> as Edna Mode from the Incredibles movie puts: "NO CAPES"

Put me together and be in awe of my brilliance!

What is the word?

> ???

Answer (score 0):

Taking the first and third clues from other replies, and thinking simply for the second, I'd guess:

> "S" is what lies before stone and tree, as it's the letter at the beginning of those two words as written. Put together your word is Inscape - sometimes a word for art similar to a landscape of the artist's mind. Which is why you say we ought to be in awe at your brilliance.

Comment: This is not the correct solution, sorry. All three parts are real words.